# Remote access for Geoserver...Local host only

Tags: jetty, geoserver

I am a GIS tech trying to get migrate to Geoserver, unfortunately I am not very savvy on web hosting.
I installed the Windows version 2.3.1.
I was able to build by map and access it through localhost:8080\geoserver\www\
I take that to mean that the jetty server it working.

I understand that I should be able to replace my local IP address where "localhost" is and be able to access it from another computer via Http.

I can't figure out the next step. I have found great tutorials on every part of geoserver process except this. And the user guide does not get into this either.

My set up: Cable Modem > Router > PC with Geoserver

What I have tried: Setting up a virtual server on my router. I have tried changing by router to inbound port 8080 to private port 8080
I also tried 80 to 8080
and 80 to 80

I also tried windows firewall exception. and turning off windows firewall.

I read about using appache tomcat but I have not installed it because it seems that jetty is working (at least as a local host) and I don't want to put another program on 8080. And to my understanding it can work stand alone but I really honestly don't know no.

I am must be missing some vital piece of information on how to do this. I am hoping it is just so basic that it wasn't worth mentioning on tutorials.

Thanks
Karin

Answer (score 0):

This would be a GeoServer configuration question, but since its deployed in jetty the solution is likely in the underlying jetty configuration.  That being said it is a guess on my part (the jetty side of things) how they set up this distribution, but if you find a jetty.xml file, perhaps under an /etc directory then you should be able to edit that file and set a proper host in the configuration.

Seriously though, this has to be a pretty common GeoServer question so I bet they have some documentation floating around for setting this properly in their software distribution.

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/basics.html

That seems to indicate it might be dependent on your container configuration, in which case look through how ever they are configuring jetty for a Host setting that is likely hardcoded to 'localhost'